# SpringBoot. One file catches CSS another doesn't

Tags: css, spring-boot

Having resource tree like this:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj5Bn.png)
File index.html sees the CSS, but file registration does not see it. Both located in one folder. Both have the same html definition:

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>All people</title>
    <link href="../../static/css/StyleCSS.css" th:href="@{css/StyleCSS.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
```

Files on [github](https://github.com/Kozlachkov/blog/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/people/registration.html)

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it is weird, but if you change

```
th:href="@{css/StyleCSS.css}"
```

to:

```
th:href="@{/css/StyleCSS.css}"
```

it is gonna work. Though I have no idea why it behaves differently on index.